# Unix: How to pass all files from a folder as args to a java program

Tags: java, unix

I have the `myJar.jar` runnable jar in `home/myJarFolder/` folder.
In `myJarFolder`, there is a folder named target that contains the following files: 
report-b-20151114.txt 
report-a-20151115.txt
report-b-20151115.txt
report-a-20151114.txt

I want to run `myJar` from its folder (home/myJarFolder/) and passing as arguments to this program all files from /target folder that end with current date.

Until now, I tried:

```
java -jar myJar.jar /target/report_*${date +'%m%d'}.txt
java -jar myJar.jar ${ls /target/report_*${date +'%m%d'}.txt}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can't you search the files inside the program instead of passing them as jvm arguments?

Comment: Or alternatively, specify the directory as an argument, and then loop over all files in that directory?

Comment: In the list of files is no file for today (GMT) only for yesterday and the day before yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file globbing pattern looks wrong. You need to use braces instead of curly brackets.

```
java -jar myJar.jar /target/report_*$(date +'%m%d').txt
```

To verify the result (for the passsed filenames) you simply can execute

```
ls /target/report_*$(date +'%m%d').txt
```

and check if the files you expect are listed.